# Adding a custom field to a slug

Tags: customization, permalinks, slug

I'm using the WP Job Manager plugin, and want to add the company name field to the slug automatically when I save a post.

I've got it working using the code below, but once I save and then edit the post again, it will re-add the company name, so *job-title-company-name* becomes *job-title-company-name-company-name*

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I think there might be an issue with my IF statement which should check if the companyname string already exists in the slug, and if so, unhook the function.

```
function custom_job_post_type_link( $post_id, $post ) {

    $permalink = $post->post_name;  
    $companyname = $post->_company_name;

    if ( strpos( $permalink, strval($companyname) ) ) {
        return;
    }
    
    // unhook this function to prevent infinite looping
    remove_action( 'save_post_job_listing', 'custom_job_post_type_link', 10, 2 );

    // add the id to the slug
    $permalink .= '-' . $companyname;

    // update the post slug
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_name' => $permalink
    ));

    // re-hook this function
    add_action( 'save_post_job_listing', 'custom_job_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
}

add_action( 'save_post_job_listing', 'custom_job_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use function `sanitize_title()` - [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/), which converts a string into a slug when you check if it is already in the permalink, and when appending it to permalink:

```
function custom_job_post_type_link( $post_id, $post ) {

    $permalink = $post->post_name;  
    $companyname = $post->_company_name;

    if ( strpos( $permalink, sanitize_title($companyname) ) ) { // <-- Here
        return;
    }
    
    // unhook this function to prevent infinite looping
    remove_action( 'save_post_job_listing', 'custom_job_post_type_link', 10, 2 );

    // add the id to the slug
    $permalink .= '-' . sanitize_title($companyname); // <-- And here

    // update the post slug
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_name' => $permalink
    ));

    // re-hook this function
    add_action( 'save_post_job_listing', 'custom_job_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
}

add_action( 'save_post_job_listing', 'custom_job_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks geouser! I just needed sanitize_title in the IF statement and now it works :)